# Hive query using tez stucks at Launching Job 1 out of 1

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I have set up hadoop single node and tested hive query on 10gb using tez engine, which was working fine. After loading 6 tb data, query stuck at Launching Job 1 out of 1. And hive log says

> Tez system stage directory
> hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/0716a629-1a1d-4500-86d9-6041aaf61596/.tez/application_1675755644314_0003
> doesn't exist and is created 2023-02-07T13:12:01,670  INFO [Tez
> session start thread] impl.YarnClientImpl: Killed application
> application_1675755644314_0002 2023-02-07T13:12:01,671 ERROR [Tez
> session start thread] tez.TezSessionState: Failed to start Tez session
> java.io.IOException: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.startSessionAndContainers(TezSessionState.java:456)
> ~[hive-exec-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.access$100(TezSessionState.java:101)
> ~[hive-exec-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState$1.call(TezSessionState.java:376)
> ~[hive-exec-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState$1.call(TezSessionState.java:371)
> ~[hive-exec-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> ~[?:1.8.0_352]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_352]
> Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted  at
> java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_352]  at
> org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.waitTillReady(TezClient.java:1020)
> ~[tez-api-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]    at
> org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.waitTillReady(TezClient.java:982)
> ~[tez-api-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]    at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.startSessionAndContainers(TezSessionState.java:453)
> ~[hive-exec-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]  ... 5 more 2023-02-07T13:12:01,833  INFO
> [93c56d8b-6e20-4b06-a5ba-1101e67ac8d7 main] impl.YarnClientImpl:
> Submitted application application_1675755644314_0003
> 2023-02-07T13:12:01,839  INFO [93c56d8b-6e20-4b06-a5ba-1101e67ac8d7
> main] client.TezClient: The url to track the Tez Session:
> http://hadoop-node:8088/proxy/application_1675755644314_0003/

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: `The url to track the Tez Session: http://hadoop-node:8088/proxy/application_1675755644314_0003/` what does that URL say?

Comment: That says YarnApplicationState: ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.